# My mom can't type in the "to" box on her work Gmail

Tags: gmail

My mom uses Brave Browser on Linux Mint (I set it up for her), and when she tries to click on the "to" box in her work Gmail nothing happens.

Comment: Trying clearing cache and try again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

switching to gmail basic html fixed the problem